# $A$ bounded implies $f(A)$ bounded? (if $f$ is continuous)

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

if $A$ is bounded and $f$ is continuous, then I know $f(A)$ is bounded... But I just can't picture it.

I keep thinking of this scenario:

$f = \frac 1x  $ is continuous (at least on $(0, \infty)$ ) and $A = (0,1)$ is bounded. But the image of $f(A)$ in this case would be $f(A) = (1, \infty)$ which is not bounded... Where is my error of logic?

Thanks for the help :D

Comment: The statement is simply not true. Replace "bounded" with "compact", though, and you're in business.

Comment: There's no error, you're right! Weierstrass theorem applies to sets that are compact, hence (in $\Bbb R$ with usual topology) bounded and *closed*

Comment: That makes me feel a lot better. It thought I was going crazy! Thanks!

Comment: Also known as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem

Comment: you do not know $f(A)$ is bounded; you just mixed it up with some other result that has different hypotheses